# fetching certificates with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

Hi I'm very new to powershell , i need to fetch only issued certificates from CA server and want to export all issued certificates to csv file  by using powershell but unable to find the exact command , any help would be appreciated.

i'm using this command to fetch issued certificates, but getting all certificates, how to filter only issued certificates?

certutil -view -out "RequestID,RequesterName,RequestType,NotAfter,CommonName,CertificateTemplate,SerialNumber"

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into using the [PKITools module](https://github.com/BladeFireLight/PKITools) as this module includes the ability to retrieve issued certificates with ease.

You should be able to install the module by issuing the following command:

```
Install-Module -Name PKITools
```

Once the module has been installed, it should be as simple as running the below (without [Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2) if you want to work with the returned data):

```
Get-IssuedCertificate | Format-Table
```

This will give you output similar to the below:

[image: Issued certificates]